# Where is relocation data stored in a PE file if not in the .reloc section?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm, portable-executable

I have the following program:

```
    BITS 32

    section .data
_num1:  dd 5    

    section .text
    global _start
_start:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, 9
    add eax, [_num2]
    sub eax, [_num1]

    leave
    ret

_num2:  dd 7
```

Which assembles into the x86 instructions below:

```
   0x00401000 <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x00401001 <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
   0x00401003 <+3>:     mov    eax,0x9
   0x00401008 <+8>:     add    eax,DWORD PTR ds:0x401016
   0x0040100e <+14>:    sub    eax,DWORD PTR ds:0x402000
   0x00401014 <+20>:    leave
   0x00401015 <+21>:    ret
```

Now, the addresses of the `sub` and `add` instructions seems pretty fixed (absolute). Indeed, the `VirtualAddress` of the .data section is `0x2000`, but what if the program doesn't load at its preferred address and relocation must be applied?

In this case, since the `VirtualAddress`'s are RVA's, the sections remain relative to each other, but the addresses above are fixed.

How does the loader know that it must change these addresses to point to the proper data items?

Comment: From the relocation table of course.  It isn't clear whether you looked at it, but in all likelihood it was removed by the linker because an EXE file that doesn't use a dynamic base never needs to be relocated.  It can always load at 0x400000, nobody to compete with.  Relocation applies to DLLs.

Comment: Just to be sure, will the relocation table always be stored in the .reloc section?

Comment: It will always be stored in a location where the loader can find it.  The 6th entry in the data directory.  It does not care about the name of the section.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant - in general, NO relocation is applied to .EXE files whatsoever? When would an .EXE use a dynamic base?